# jQuery can detect select value on change but not on page load?

Tags: jquery

I have a select element on my page with the name booking[car_id]

I can detect the value when the option is changed but if I try and get the value when the page loads, I just get 'undefined'.

So, this works OK:

```
$('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]').change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

This returns undefined:

```
alert($('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]').value);
```

Am I missing something simple?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]')[0].value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `val` method, jQuery object doesn't have `value` property, also make sure that DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){
  alert($('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]').val());
});
```

You can also trigger the `change` event, so the handler is executed on page load:

```
$('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]').change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert($('select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the functionality of the javascript DOM instead of the $ obj `.val()`

```
alert($("select[name=booking\\[car_id\\]]").val());
```